# Storage Access Framework ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT on Google Drive results in 0 byte file sometimes

Tags: android, google-drive-api, storage-access-framework

Suddendly my app's Google Drive backup/restore via Storage Access Framework feature stopped working properly. Users report it failing sometimes, and sometimes not, without a clear reason. Internal or external storage options instead work as expected.

This is my code:

```
private void createDocument(String fileName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("application/json");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, fileName);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.message_saf_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CREATE_DOCUMENT && uri != null) {
            ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(Uri.parse(uriString), "w");
            if (fileDescriptor != null) {
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
                // Write bytes...
                fileOutputStream.close();
                fileDescriptor.close();
            }
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I debugged my code and experienced this strange behavior. 
If data to write is little and code is executed almost immediately it works most of the times.
If data is big (and usually is, around 10MB) or I put a breakpoint on my onActivityResult method openFileDescriptor or FileOutputStream creation throw a FileNotFoundException or even if that exception is not raised it fails silently and resulting file on Google Drive is 0 bytes long.

I even tried putting the ParcelFileDescriptor/FileOutputStream part in a background thread, AsyncTask, Worker without any luck. Problem is the same.

This is upsetting my users and making my ratings go way down. I'm sure I didn't anything on my code in the last two months, so the problem must be elsewhere, but I don't know...

EDIT: I might add that is seems somehow related to the Google Drive app, because if I clear its data or cache the subsequent uploads work fine, until it breaks again.

Comment: My devices received 2.19.112.05.40 and it seems to work